# How can I get the sorted string and max value by word count from all string?

Tags: java, sorting

I have the following java code. I want to get sorted string by their word count and max value word count in all string. Please help me! I have tried the following java code.

```
public class sort {


  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 

   {

    /*buffer have many string such as::
                                        meno-pause=ge40 #SUP: 3
                                        breast-quard=left_low #SUP: 6
                                        age=40-49 #SUP: 5
                                        age=60-69,meno-pause=ge40 #SUP: 3
                                        age=60-69,meno-pause=ge40,node-caps=no #SUP: 3
                                        age=60-69,meno-pause=ge40,node-caps=no,Class=no-recurrence-events #SUP: 3
                                        age=60-69,meno-pause=ge40,node-caps=no,Class=no-recurrence-events,irradiat=no #SUP: 3
                                        age=60-69,meno-pause=ge40,node-caps=no,Class=no-recurrence-events,inv-nodes=0-2 #SUP: 3*/

            HashMap<String,Integer> freqK = new HashMap<>();
            String[] lineSplit = null;
            StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
            ArrayList<String> a=new ArrayList<String>();
            String[] line=buffer.toString().split("#");
                    freqK.put(line[0],support);
                    //System.out.println(freqK);
                    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : freqK.entrySet()) 
                    {
                        String key = entry.getKey();                
                        a.add(key);
                        Integer value = entry.getValue();

                         //System.out.println(lineSplit.length);
                    }
                    int[] count=new int[a.size()];
                    for(int i=0;i<a.size();i++)
                    {
                         lineSplit=a.get(i).split(","); 
                         count[i]=lineSplit.length;
                    }
                    //System.out.println(lineSplit);
                    int max = count[0];
                    for(int i = 1; i < count.length;i++)
                    {
                        if(count[i] > max)
                        {
                            max = count[i];
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println("From The Array Element Largest Number is:" + max);
        }
    }
```

Comment: *I want to get sorted string by their word count and max value word count in all string*, could you please explain a bit more in detail what you are trying to achieve? Do you want to sort `String`s descending by their amount of words?

Comment: Could you please give us the value of the variable `support`?

Comment: It would help a lot if you could add an *example input* as well as your *desired output*

Comment: In above, buffer have string and their support values like that  meno-pause=ge40 #SUP: 3 ; in this support values is 3.

Comment: Input string like that ::   meno-pause=ge40 #SUP: 3
                                    age=60-69,meno-pause=ge40 #SUP: 3
                                    age=60-69,meno-pause=ge40,node-caps=no #SUP: 3
                                    breast-quard=left_low #SUP: 6
                                    age=40-49 #SUP: 5And I want to get like that ; meno-pause=ge40 #SUP: 3
age=40-49 #SUP: 5
breast-quard=left_low #SUP: 6
age=60-69,meno-pause=ge40 #SUP: 3
 age=60-69,meno-pause=ge40,node-caps=no #SUP: 3. They can split by "," and then sort their word count.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the sample input and resulting output that you wrote in the comment. Also try to format the input and output so it is easy to understand what you are trying to achieve.